# How to install on documents folder at any computer Express VS 2015

Tags: c#, express, visual-studio-2015, desktop-application, installation-path

Yo. How do I make this from Express Visual Studio for Desktop 2015:

[image: from Visual Studio 2015 deployment]

Point towards a Documents folder on any given computer (current user)? Because I can only make it install on my computer's specific documents folder, and my googling doesn't give me much insight (especially since all of the results point towards earlier versions which I find no resemblance to with Express 2015).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you misunderstand what that publishing path is for.  That isn't how applications get *installed*, it's the location that the files get pushed to so that they can get installed *from* there.  It's also used for web applications to push the app out to the web server.

This [extension](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/f1cc3f3e-c300-40a7-8797-c509fb8933b9) will help you create an actual setup project, if that's what you are trying to do.

Comment: Then where and how do I specify the installation?

Comment: Check out the extension link at the end of my answer.  You need to create an `Installer Project`.

Comment: You can also jump directly to Flexera's Install shield here http://learn.flexerasoftware.com/content/IS-EVAL-InstallShield-Limited-Edition-Visual-Studio.  But I find it way more complicated.